# How to set route table permanently

Tags: networking

How can I permanently set a route table in Ubuntu kernel IP routing table? When I restart my PC the route table entry is getting auto flushed. I am using this command for route table entry:

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 dev ens4
```